# Yjs and codemirror with action cable, no errors but it doesn't do anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, codemirror, collaborative-editing

I am trying to use [yrb-actioncable](https://github.com/y-crdt/yrb-actioncable) on Rails with [yjs](https://github.com/yjs/yjs) on Angular to have a collaborative text editor, I've never used ActionCable, Angular, Y.js, or CodeMirror before so I faced a lot of errors trying to make it work, I finally thought I had it when I stopped seeing any errors, but actually it still doesn't work.

I can see the editor on the screen and I can use collaborative editing between tabs of the same browser, I can see the requests to and from actioncable, but nothing else.

[This is the whole repository](https://github.com/DJA89/crdt_yjs_matefun/tree/add_collaborative_eidition_libraries_for_help), it's kind of a mess but I don't really know Angular and it's just a proof of concept to try and make things work. The [DocumentChannel](https://github.com/DJA89/crdt_yjs_matefun/tree/add_collaborative_eidition_libraries_for_help/backend/app/channels/application_cable/document_channel.rb) is the ActionCable part, the [code-editor](https://github.com/DJA89/crdt_yjs_matefun/tree/add_collaborative_eidition_libraries_for_help/frontend/src/app/code-editor/code-editor.component.ts) is the Angular component part. I'll paste them below too removing the commented and unused parts

```rb
require 'y-rb'

module ApplicationCable
  class DocumentChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
    include Y::Actioncable::Sync

    def initialize(connection, identifier, params = nil)
      super
      load { |id| load_doc 1 }
    end

    def subscribed
      sync_from("document-1")
    end

    def receive(data)
      sync_to("document-1", data)
    end

    def unsubscribed
    end

    private

    def load_doc(id)
      doc_content = Document.first.content
      ydoc = Y::Doc.new
      ytext = ydoc.get_text('mine')
      ytext << doc_content
      data = []
      data = ydoc.diff unless doc_content.nil?
      data
    end
  end
end
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http'
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Y from "yjs";
import { WebsocketProvider } from "@y-rb/actioncable";
import CodeMirror from "codemirror";
import { CodeMirrorBinding } from 'y-codemirror'
import ActionCable from 'actioncable'

@Component({
  selector: 'code-editor',
  templateUrl: './code-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./code-editor.component.scss']
})
export class CodeEditorComponent implements OnInit {
 

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
    const uid = localStorage.getItem('uid')
    const client = localStorage.getItem('client')

    const yDocument = new Y.Doc();
    const consumer = ActionCable.createConsumer(`ws://localhost:3000/cable?uid=${uid}&access-token=${accessToken}&client=${client}`);
    const provider = new WebsocketProvider(
      yDocument,
      consumer,
      "ApplicationCable::DocumentChannel",
      {}
    );
    const yText = yDocument.getText('codemirror')

    const yUndoManager = new Y.UndoManager(yText)

    const editorContainer = document.createElement('div')
    editorContainer.setAttribute('id', 'editor')
    document.body.insertBefore(editorContainer, null)

    const editor = CodeMirror(editorContainer, {
      mode: 'javascript',
      lineNumbers: true,
    })

    const binding = new CodeMirrorBinding(yText, editor, provider.awareness, { yUndoManager })

    // @ts-ignore
    //window.example = { provider, ydoc, yText, binding, Y }
  }
}
```

I can't seem to find what's wrong with it as I don't get any actual error, nor have I been able to get any more help from online guides nor the official docs that I've tried following. Could anyone guide me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I managed to make it work, my frontend code didn't change much, but my backend code did, you can see the end result [in this link](https://github.com/DJA89/crdt_yjs_matefun), but I'll paste the channel here so you can see the differences.

```rb
    # This method initializes the channel when someone tries to subscribe to it
    # and there's no one here yet
    # I imagine we should check here wether the document belongs to the user or not
    def initialize(connection, identifier, params = nil)
      super
      # This is a method from Y::Actioncable
      # it should return the full_diff of this channel's document
      load { load_doc 1 }
    end

    # This method is called when someone subscribes to this channel
    # If #initialize is called, this method will be called after
    # that one
    def subscribed
      # This method is from Y::Actioncable
      # It's just to facilitate set up, you should pass the actual
      # document you want to sync (here we are always syncing the first document).
      # The block is to save the document after syncing
      sync_for(Document.first) do |id, update|
        # Save it on the database
        save_doc(id, update)
      end
    end

    # Each time a change happens on the web this method will be
    # called with the new data to update our document
    def receive(data)
      # With this we spread the new data to all subscribers
      # so everyone is up to date with the document
      sync_to(Document.first, data)
      # Update the doc on the database, it would be good to not do
      # this every time this method is called, or maybe delay it
      # so it doesn't block every request
      save_doc(id, update)
    end

    # This method is called when a subscriber stops using the document
    def unsubscribed
    end

    private

    def load_doc(id)
      # For this POC we are using only the one document
      # otherwise we should look for the document with the given id
      doc_content = JSON.parse(Document.first.binary_doc)

      # Return the document binary
      doc_content
    end

    def save_doc(id, update)
      # Since we are only using the one document on this POC
      # We update that document only, otherwise we should look
      # for the correct document to update
      Document.first.update(binary_doc: update)
    end
```

Now I'm glad to say it works just fine ^^